# Android Firebase population to listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Need a help with population Firebase information to ListView. I need to get all childs from "Shops", but cant. Who knows how to solve please help. While print message it giving me correct Array but I cant implement it to ListView.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dealer_list_view);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dealer_listView);

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot friendsSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("Shops");
            for (DataSnapshot friendSnapshot : friendsSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                String message = friendSnapshot.child("Dealer").getValue(String.class);
                System.out.println(message);

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("My URl"+message);

                FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(DealerListView.this,
                        String.class,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        ref) {

                    @Override
                    protected void populateView(View v, String s, int i) {

     TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        textView.setText(s);
                   }
                };
                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Update

```
  - Shops
         -AAA
             Dealer: "AAA"
             Email: "a@mail.ru"
             SAP:   "D666"
         -BBB
             Dealer: "BBB"
             Email:  "r@mail.ru"
             SAP:     "D333"
         -CCC
             Dealer:  "BBB"
             Email:   "g@mail.ru"
             SAP:     "D222"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshot please) that this code is accessing.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: Here you can find perfect examples using a ListView and a RecyclerView:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: By the way, I think that _dealer_ isn't a direct child from _Shops_...

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're overcomplicating matters. This should be the only code you need:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Shops");

FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
    DealerListView.this,
    String.class,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    ref) {
        protected void populateView(View v, String s, int i) {
          TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
          textView.setText(s);
        }
        protected String parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            return snapshot.child("Dealer").getValue(String.class);
        }
};
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

So with this code you have a list of Shop snapshots and then for each snapshot extract the value of the `Dealer` property in `parseSnapshot`

Comment: Thank you, listview return correct number of rows, I see them, but they are empty no "Dealer" names.

Comment: Can I get any example of this extracting, I am new in Java, it will help me to understand what exactly I have to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll want to run the code in a debugger and see what you get in `parseSnapshot()`.